# What is a good approach for scaling/drawing images for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios

In my iPhone app, I have a control that takes on quite different sizes on different screens. For example, (in the iOS point coordinates)

- 3.5 inch devices (iPhone 4S): 242x295
- 4 inch devices (iPhone 5 series, SE): 242x383
- 4.7 inch devices (iPhone 6 series): 297x482
- 5.5 inch devices (iPhone 6 Plus series): 336x551

As you can see, these control sizes are *not* proportional.

**The problem**

This control has an image as its background. That particular image is important for brand identity and the custom appearance that my company's designer wants to go with. The image gives the appearance of a material and has a texture. It also has shadows within itself. I would like to apply this image on to controls of different screen sizes (my control sizes are determined at runtime according to available space, as Apple may come up with new screen sizes anytime).

**My current solution**

The designer makes separate PNGs for me for each screen size and I hard code it with onto my control using an if-else for screen size (after determining the size mathematically before hand). As you can probably tell, this is a horrible approach for robustness. I'm also looking to expand to iPad and having a better scaling system will certainly help.

**An idea**
I take an image that's the smallest unit of the repeating texture and apply it to my control with the scaling option that repeats it throughout to obtain a final image.
HOWEVER, I lose my shadows and rounded edges this way. (I tried simply using the  largest image as well and the disproportionate scaling makes the rounded edges horrible)

I tried looking for solutions and most resources do not deal with such images. I simply cannot lose any part of this image and it should be fully applied to the control, shadows and corners included.

I apologize if any or all of this is naive or if I didn't look for answers using the correct words. This is my first time posting here at Stack Overflow, and I'm looking forward to hearing from you guys.

Thanks!

p

Edit:

[image]

This is applied to a custom UIButton based control to give the appearance of a card.

**Edit 2: Wain seems to have suggested a perfect answer. I will try it and let everyone know the results.**

Comment: show some examples of the images

Comment: @Wain good idea. I added an image in the original post but can't embed it yet. (Reputation points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use tiling as you describe, and I'd combine that with changing the view layer corner radius and applying a shadow offset. In this way you can separate the important part of the image and make it nicely reusable and you can leverage the capability of `CALayer`.

Note that when you set the `shadowOffset` of the layer you should also look at the `shadowColor`, `shadowRadius` and `shadowOpacity`.

Comment: I like this approach because it potentially saves space and memory and is more robust (although drawing the image should use more processing. That should be minor, right?). I had a major lethologica about tiling -- thanks for that too.

Comment: Yes, the system offers this feature, it's so fast you won't notice and difference and it's probably actually faster because the tile is fast to load and easier to copy in the UI buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can used `Assets.xcassets` for managing images in ios. you can make image in 1x,2x and 3x scale.

For example you want an icon of size 50x50 pixel then 1x should be 50x50,
2x should be 100x100 and 3x should be 150x150. then ios automatically take appropriate image from this set.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Okay, I understand the idea of using 2x and 3x images. But suppose I have a UIImageView that displays a (theoretically) 50x50 image on iPhone 5. Now on iPhone 6, I would like it to display a 60x60 image instead as the image is the main control on the screen. Is it possible to do *that*?

Comment: yes, you can do that by different ways. you can change frame of imageView as per screen size (worst way according to me because requite to many if else to detect different screen size) and another way is autolayout (best way). If you want dynamically height - width according to screen size you can do with autolayout but it requires good command over it.

Comment: Thanks, @Lion. I'm still concerned about scaling. I understand that on an iPhone 6P, where everything is *actually* 3x, using a 50x50 image will only generate a 150x150 result. If you try to stretch it to 180x180 (as would be required for 60x60), the result will be blurry. I can imagine that on the iPhone 6 and 5, this problem is worked around as the system could downscale the 3x image instead.

Comment: You can use largest image. If you require maximum 180 as 3x then you can use 60,120 and 180. and if you use this image in lower size imageview then it will not create any problem i think.

Comment: Image view have different mode that you can use as per requirement like scale to fill, aspect fill, aspect fit etc.

Comment: That brings us back to square one on the disproportional image sizes issue. I feel @Wain's approach is best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109508/discussion-between-derpity-derp-and-lion).

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ration of iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6P are almost same. however the aspect ration of iPhone 4 is different.

Here is the steps which helps you.

- So you need one image which image is suitable for iPhone 5 and its
  @2x, and @3x image and iPhone 4 and its @2x image,

  i.e if you have image with 242x383 for iPhone 5 then you need images
  with its @2x, and @3x images. and you need image which is compatible
  with iPhone 4 size.
- You need to set `UIImageView's` contentMode as `aspectFit`.

So the idea is, make **iPhone 5's image and its @2x, @3x images** and **iPhone 4's** image differently. or you can put all things in UIScrollView and for iPhone 4 set contentSize of scrollView is 568. and make different image for iPad.

Comment: That's similar to the approach I'm using right now. But as I move to iPad, I again have to make different images (but all of them are the same ratio, right?). Isn't there a better approach that doesn't involve making separate images whenever Apple comes up with a different screen?

Comment: Additionally, the iPhone 6 and 6P have more screen real estate. If I'm simply using a smaller size, I'll not be able to utilize all of the available space. Are you saying that iOS automatically uses the 2x and 3x images to perfectly scale a smaller image on to a larger control?

Comment: i had updated my answer, for iPad you have to create different image, And for iPhone 6P are using the @3x image, for resizing the control you must use the autoresizing or autolayout.

Comment: Will autoresizing be able to perfectly scale a smaller image onto a larger canvas? I do not think that is physically possible. Explain.

Comment: yes it will be run perfectly for simple design, but whenever there are complex design, then the better way is to create different storybord or xib for iPhone and iPad.